# How to append an array of space-separated integers input in an array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, input

I want to append user input of space-separated integers, as integers not array, into a formed array. Is there a way to do this?

Here is a pseudo-code:

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
a.append(int(input().split())
print(a)
```

I want it to be time-efficient, this is what I tried:

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
b=list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
a.extend(b)
print(a)
```

Is there a more efficient / faster way?

Expected output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
# When input is '5 6 7 8'
```

Comment: If it's user input, the time efficiency won't matter, as the user'll take way more time to type in (or pipe from a file) the input than it can basically ever take for your code to parse things.

Comment: This is just for ease of explanation of the question. The point of the question is time efficiency. I want to take input **and** append it into a list. There is a longer code ahead. I just wanted to know if there is a fast way to do it.
(Like appending the input while taking it, which would be possible if the input was given one by one.)

Comment: Reading and parsing one-by-one would be slower. Your way is reasonably fast, in any case, but in the grand scheme of things it _likely_ won't matter (and when you profile your larger program and find integer reading to be a bottleneck, you can speed it up).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so:

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
a.extend(map(int, input().split()))
print(a)
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it as :

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
b=list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
for i in b:
    a.append(i)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by joining two lists using '+' operator -

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
result = list(map(int, input().split())) + a
```

## Output

[5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4]